# How to auto scale a floating point value in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

I am working on embedded device which measures voltage via a 16 bit ADC.
With 3.3V as reference I have a resolution of 50uV. So, the device can measure from 50uV to 3.3V and as such based on the current value I need to format it and display it in mV or uV or V etc.

The value is a floating point.

Is there existing library API that does that or should I write my own code?

Comment: You should write some code for this.

Comment: so there is no existing algorithm which i can use?

Comment: It is just not clear

Comment: You mean... just changing the scale units?  I suppose some mult/div by 10^stuff will be needed.  Your Q. is very unclear:(

Comment: There is no standard code that does the job.  You face several issues: (1) how to scale the number so it gives an appropriate value in the range 1..999; (2) how to print the units multiplier; (3) how to control/present the number of digits (435 vs 434.7 vs 434.68 (3-5 digits); also 1.23 vs 12.3 vs 123 (decimal places or not, and how many), etc.

Comment: I have re-phrased the question. Sorry about the clarity part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to auto scale a floating point value in C?

Auto scaling to powers of 1000s has subtle considerations near the transitions that even had OP coded it, it likely would have failed in corner cases.

Let us try a slightly different, yet simpler goal: print to 3 significant digits and at powers of 1000.0

```
// example output
1.00
9.99
10.0
99.9
100.
999.
1.00k
9.99k
10.0k
...
```

---

Code can try to do this with its own math using `log()`, etc., but will invariable fail with cases near 9.995, 99.95, 999.5.

Let `sprintf()` do  the heavy lifting and then use string manipulation.

---

The first step is to print to a string using `"%e"`

```
//            sgn  dig  . digs  e  sgn expo \0 
#define FLT_E2 (1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 5 + 1)
// let us double buffer size as there is little reason to be stingy here.
char buf[FLT_E2 * 2];  

//                           v--- 2 digits after the lead digit
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.2e", some_float);
```

The next step is to process the string into its 3 parts and use `"%n"` to note the offset of the decimal point and `'e'`.

```
int whole, frac, expo, dp, e;
if (sscanf(buf, "%d%n.%d%ne%d", &whole, &dp, &frac, &e, &expo) != 3) {
  // value is some non-finite like infinity or not-a-number.
  printf("%e", some_float);  
  return;
}
```

Now move `expo` down to a multiple of 3 and shift the decimal point.

```
while (expo%3) {
  expo--;
  buf[dp] = buf[dp+1];
  buf[++dp] = '.';
}
```

Convert the `'e'` into the various [SI prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix).

```
// TBD code to handle expo out of range [-24 24], left for OP.

char prefix = "yzafpnum kMGTPEZY"[(expo - -24)/3];
if (prefix != ' ') buf[e++] = prefix;
buf[e] = '\0';
```

Now print

```
printf("%s", buf);
```

---

Although there is much detail here with these unchecked code snippets, the final code is left for OP to form.

Advanced issue include:
  handling locale specific decimal points like `','`
  exponents [outside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#X,_W_and_V) [-24...24].
  μ vs u.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I will use this for my requirement here. Thanks again. :)